# Does anyone know a good jQuery content slider that auto resizes the height of the containing div depending on content?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-slider

I am building a website and have a div containing quotes from books. I would ideally like the div to show one quote at a time and probably just fade in and out between them. I was thinking of using something like the jQuery Cycle plugin and having prev and next arrows.

The quotes however are purely textual and are of various lengths, therefore it would be nice if I could perhaps get the bottom of the containing div to slide up and down depending on the height of the content within.

Any ideas would be great. I'm sure I've seen this kind of thing about before, but just can't seem to find anything that similar just now. The closest I have seen is coda slider 2, but I don't really need the tabs.

Any advice would be great! :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some nice ones:

[Quovolver](http://sandbox.sebnitu.com/jquery/quovolver/) (Maybe the best one, cycles and adjusts size)

[jQuery Quote Rotator Plugin](http://coryschires.com/jquery-quote-rotator-plugin/) (Doesn't adjust size as far as I know)

[Random Content Generator](http://3nhanced.com/examples/randomContent/) (Doen't rotate without refresh)

Good luck!

Comment: Wow... thanks for the speedy reply! Quovolver looks like it could be just the thing I'm looking for.

Comment: No problem! glad to help! The installation is straight forward too! good luck, please tell me if you need anything else! and remember that google is your friend :) http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+quote

Comment: I've just found this one also that looks like it has an auto height setting :o) http://slidesjs.com/